# Where Is The Installer For Open Source Qt4?

Tags: c++, qt, installation

I've been looking for an hour now, I go here: http://qt-project.org/downloads, but there are no installers for Qt. It has the source code ("Qt libraries"), and the installer for Qt Creator, which I downloaded and installed, but a bunch of the stuff in Qt Creator is missing (Ex. project types, "kits"), and I'm guessing this is because I need to install Qt4 itself, which I cannot find!

I'm asking this because I installed Qt4 fine on another computer, but I forget where I got it from. http://qt.digia.com/Try-Qt-Now/ will get me the SDK but it's the trial version, I want the open source free version.

Where do I get this! I know it's out there because I installed it on another computer a few weeks ago, and all I had to to was run a simple .exe file to install it (and I know for a fact it was a legitimate copy, not some pirated version).

Also, I want to be able to use it with QMake And QCreator so I would assume that one of the packages like this: "Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB)" would not work?

PS. To whoever nice guys decided to vote down/close this project, I'm fairly sure this fits in this category: "software tools commonly used by programmers", which is one of the questions the SO FAQ says are appropriate to ask on this website.

Comment: With a "problem" solved by merely visiting the very links you list, this is a problem only local to you. As such I voted to close this as "too localized". That said, "where do I download X" is not really a programming related problem. If it's on-topic it's only marginally so.

Comment: @Bart what should I have done instead, downloaded every 250mb package until something worked? The download link packages were very unclear, and I couldn't find anything else on the internet to tell me what to do...

Comment: And you've gotten your answer. Good for you. This isn't a personal thing. But when a question asks "Where can I download X, I've looked at site Y" and the answer is "Well....site Y really", then it's simply a problem local to you. I.e. you overlooked it. Fair enough, can happen, but as a question it's too localized. As for the on-topic-ness, just because it's sideways related to programming, doesn't make it on-topic. But anyway, that was not my close vote. If you want clarification, or perhaps wonder if I'm wrong, by all means ask on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there on http://qt-project.org/downloads. "Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows" (various versions, for MinGW and Visual Studio.) I don't see how you can miss it :-/

Comment: ...and here I was looking if I was somehow missing the point. Right there indeed.

Comment: I want to use QMake and QCreator though, will this still work?

Comment: @ForgiveMeI'mAN00b Yes. The SDK was using a single installer for the Qt libraries and Creator. You can just as well install them on their own.

Comment: well I will try that, its downloading right now. I'll accept your answer if it works :)